# How can I use WSO2 API Manager to store user accounts upon sign-up on my app, and use it for token generation?

Tags: authentication, wso2

How can a app (or microservice) talk to the API manager instance to create user account and generate JWT?

I have tried the WSO2 APIM and Istio integration (https://github.com/wso2/istio-apim#istio-mixer-adapter-for-wso2-api-manager).  However, I find this way as developer access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of the WSO2 APIM (2.6.0), Then at the time you create the application you could specify the type of token as JWT and get the JWT token.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaYJB.png)

But the use of this JWT is limited for the micro gateway for the time being.